# How to get a cookie from a different domain within HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cookies

I have this setup where if the user clicks on a link on a page which has the domain `start.example.com` that requires authentication it will redirect them to `auth.example.com` for them to enter a username and password, which if its entered correctly, it will redirect them back to the `start.example.com` domain to continue with what they're doing with a cookie, that it set to expire in a week, and can be used on any subdomain using: `domain: .example.com`.

However whenever I check to see if the cookie exists on the front end of `start.example.com` to determine if they need to authenticate themselves or not, it doesn't work.

So hence my question: how would I check to see if a cookie exists from a different domain. I have this code which returns true or false:

```
    function check_cookie_name(name) 
    {
    var match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));
        if (match) {
            return true
            console.log(match[2]);
        }
        else{
            return false
            console.log('--something went wrong---');
        }
    }
```

However, I suspect this only works on the domain it's currently on. When I look at the cookies (after authenticating) on the `start.example.com` domain, I have two separate domains:

```
example.com
```

Which contains the auth-token that needs to be checked and

```
start.example.com
```

which contains stuff irrelevant to this question.

I suppose the code is checking the cookies of `start.example.com` and not `example.com`?

Comment: If the cookie was set with `domain: .example.com`, then it should be available to JS code running under `start.example.com`. Are you sure the issue is not rather that the cookie was maybe set as HTTP only to begin with?

Comment: I can show you the code from my server for when it gives the cookie? I mean the cookie is only set to secure, not http only

Comment: And `start.example.com` is accessed via HTTPS as well?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, everything is

Comment: And the cookie wasn’t set to be valid under a specific path only either? Please show how you are setting it, and also what it looks like when you inspect the cookies for `start.example.com` in the browser dev tools.